# wp-admin is blocking my mobile menu icon

Tags: menus

My wp-admin bar blocks my mobile menu.  How do I prevent that from happening? It forces me to have a top margin that I don't want when users are not signed in. Here's what it looks like when users are not signed in.
[image]

Comment: You can set the top margin to only apply when users are logged in.  The WP body tag has `class="logged-in admin-bar"` when a user is logged in, so you can write your CSS to add the margin only if those classes exist on the body tag:  ie. `body.logged-in.admin-bar > elementwithmargin{ margin-top:32px; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the admin toolbar when viewing the site when a user is logged in. You can do this on a per user basis by going into their profile and unchecking the checkbox for `Show toolbar when viewing site` or you can do this for all users (including admin users) using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```